# Filter ruins performance of index scan when paginating while row-comparing multi-column index to a row fetched in a subquery

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, database-indexes

I want to implement efficient pagination in Postgresql (14.5): give me a few rows associated with some `a`, that come immediately after some `b`. Unfortunately `Index Cond` disappears from under the `Index Only Scan` as soon as I try to fetch the `a` and `b` values from the database itself. Is there a way to avoid it?

The last query in this long list is doing what I want, but slowly. Everything else is presented for completeness to showcase different aspects of the problem.

## Creating table and data

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, a INT NOT NULL, b INT NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_a_b ON foo (a, b);

INSERT INTO foo (a, b) 
SELECT *
FROM generate_series(0, 9) a_table 
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 100000) b_table;
```

## Static starting point, row comparison, lower bound

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (5, 50000) < (a, b)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.43..0.69 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.051..0.056 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.43..31717.57 rows=367608 width=8) (actual time=0.049..0.052 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (ROW(a, b) > ROW(5, 50000))
         Heap Fetches: 3
 Planning Time: 0.171 ms
 Execution Time: 0.113 ms
```

Lightning fast!

## Static starting point, reversed row comparison, lower bound

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (a, b) > (5, 50000)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.51 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.048..0.051 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..11350.75 rows=398533 width=8) (actual time=0.046..0.048 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (ROW(a, b) > ROW(5, 50000))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.169 ms
 Execution Time: 0.089 ms
```

Still lightning fast!

## Static starting point, element, lower bound

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (5 = a AND 50000 < b) OR 5 < a
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                            QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.66 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=68.243..68.244 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..33480.43 rows=428662 width=8) (actual time=68.241..68.242 rows=3 loops=1)
         Filter: (((5 = a) AND (50000 < b)) OR (5 < a))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 550000
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.216 ms
 Execution Time: 68.277 ms
```

Filter kills performance. Lesson learned: optimizer in to smart enough, so just stick to row comparisons.

## Inline starting point, row comparison, lower bound

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (SELECT ROW(a, b) FROM foo WHERE id = 550000) < (a, b)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3
;
                                                             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8.87..9.12 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=137.267..137.268 rows=3 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo foo_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.021..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 550000)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..28480.42 rows=333333 width=8) (actual time=137.264..137.265 rows=3 loops=1)
         Filter: ($0 < ROW(a, b))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 550000
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.219 ms
 Execution Time: 137.310 ms
```

Filter kills performance.

## Inline starting point, reversed row comparison, lower bound

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (a, b) > (SELECT ROW(a, b) FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3


ERROR:  subquery has too few columns
LINE 3: WHERE  (a, b) > (SELECT ROW(a, b) FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
```

Failure. A wat moment for me. Could be a bug.

## Static starting point, row comparison, lower bound and upper bound

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (5, 50000) < (a, b) AND (a, b) < (440, 35)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.52 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.055..0.058 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..12347.08 rows=398533 width=8) (actual time=0.052..0.054 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((ROW(a, b) > ROW(5, 50000)) AND (ROW(a, b) < ROW(440, 35)))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.224 ms
 Execution Time: 0.104 ms
```

Lightning fast still!

## Static starting point, row comparison, fixed first column and lower bounded second column

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (5, 50000) < (a, b) AND a = 5
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                          QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..0.52 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=4.579..4.581 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..1237.23 rows=39840 width=8) (actual time=4.576..4.578 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((ROW(a, b) > ROW(5, 50000)) AND (a = 5))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.213 ms
 Execution Time: 4.622 ms
```

Much slower, but tolerable. Optimizer is smart enough to combine and equality and the row comparison together and to preserve the `Index Cond`.

## Starting point from `WITH` clause, row comparison, fixed first column and lower bounded second column

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
WITH starting_point AS (SELECT ROW(a, b) r FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (SELECT r FROM starting_point) < (a, b) AND a = (SELECT a FROM starting_point)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                              QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8.89..100.63 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=136.362..136.365 rows=3 loops=1)
   CTE starting_point
     ->  Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo foo_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.025..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 550000)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  CTE Scan on starting_point  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..50980.43 rows=1667 width=8) (actual time=136.359..136.361 rows=3 loops=1)
         Filter: (($1 < ROW(a, b)) AND (a = (SubPlan 3)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 550000
         Heap Fetches: 0
         SubPlan 3
           ->  CTE Scan on starting_point starting_point_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 0.311 ms
 Execution Time: 136.423 ms
```

This is the query that I want to run faster.

## UPD: Slight improvement.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
WITH starting_point AS (SELECT ROW(a, b) r, a FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (SELECT r FROM starting_point) < (a, b) AND a = (SELECT a FROM starting_point)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8.91..9.19 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=41.532..41.535 rows=3 loops=1)
   CTE starting_point
     ->  Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo foo_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.036..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 550000)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  CTE Scan on starting_point  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
     ->  CTE Scan on starting_point starting_point_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.041..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..3100.43 rows=33333 width=8) (actual time=41.529..41.530 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (a = $2)
         Filter: ($1 < ROW(a, b))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 50000
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.314 ms
 Execution Time: 41.598 ms
```

For some reason this is somewhat faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer of jjanes, here's what I ended up having:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
WITH starting_point AS (SELECT a, b FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE
  (a, b) > (SELECT * FROM starting_point)
  AND a <= (SELECT a FROM starting_point)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8.91..9.00 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.096..0.100 rows=3 loops=1)
   CTE starting_point
     ->  Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo foo_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 550000)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1,$2)
     ->  CTE Scan on starting_point  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.027..0.030 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 3 (returns $3)
     ->  CTE Scan on starting_point starting_point_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..3442.65 rows=111111 width=8) (actual time=0.093..0.095 rows=3 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((ROW(a, b) > ROW($1, $2)) AND (a <= $3))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.566 ms
 Execution Time: 0.160 ms
```

Learnings:

1. Subqueries in the where clause must be on the right of the comparison for some reason, otherwise the optimizer gets confused.
2. `ROW()` should be avoided, otherwise the planner fails.
3. Both conditions must be inequalities, otherwise the performance suffers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why it works this way, but just remove the `row()` from the one that fails and it will succeed and use the fast plan:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE (a, b) > (SELECT a, b FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3
```

But if you reverse the comparison, then this `row()`-less select construct fails for returning too many columns, go figure.  Maybe when the `select` comes after the main table `(a,b)`, it then knows what to expect from the select and so analyzes it correctly.

Comment: Thanks jjanes! Your comment was spot on. I reworked it a bit to also include the equality on `a` (that's what I really wanted to do). I posted the final solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the rows that *match the* `a` of some starting row and are *greater than* `b` of that row, why not use the simplest possible query:

```
WITH starting_point AS (SELECT a, b FROM foo WHERE id = 550000)
SELECT a, b
FROM foo
WHERE
  a = (SELECT a FROM starting_point) and
  b > (SELECT b FROM starting_point)
ORDER BY a, b
LIMIT 3;
```

The execution plan is as expected

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=8.91..9.00 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.041..0.042 rows=3 loops=1)                                              
  CTE starting_point                                                                                                           
    ->  Index Scan using foo_pkey on foo foo_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)     
          Index Cond: (id = 550000)                                                                                            
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)                                                                                                      
    ->  CTE Scan on starting_point  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)                 
  InitPlan 3 (returns $2)                                                                                                      
    ->  CTE Scan on starting_point starting_point_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using foo_a_b on foo  (cost=0.42..1035.08 rows=33333 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.041 rows=3 loops=1)  
        Index Cond: ((a = $1) AND (b > $2))                                                                                    
        Heap Fetches: 0                                                                                                        
Planning Time: 0.113 ms                                                                                                        
Execution Time: 0.096 ms
```